# prove that the set A/B is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

So I have this question in my math homework, and I really have no idea how to prove it, could someone please help me?

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ and $B\subset \mathbb R$ be two compact sets such that $\alpha = \inf B$ satisfies $\alpha > 0$.

Let $A/B = \{x/y \mid x\in A \text{ and } y \in B\}$. Prove that $A/B$ is compact.

My definition of compactness is the following:

Let $X$ be a metric space. A set $E \subset X$ is compact if and only if for each open cover $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of $E$ indexed by some set $I$, there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and indices $\alpha_i \in I$ such that $E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{\alpha_i}$.

Sorry for the bad writing, but I don't know how to use the math notations.

Comment: Do you know the following: (1) for positive reals, the multiplication is continuous, (2) the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact (3) a product of compact sets is compact?

Comment: yes i do, a lot of people told me that it is sufficient to prove that AxB is compact, but how could i use it here?

Comment: You actually need the inversion $\iota\colon x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}$ to be continuous as well (which it is). Then you can take the set $B$, apply the $\iota$ to it and get the compact set $1/B = \{ \frac{1}{b}\ |\ b\in B\}$, and then the multiplication from $A\times 1/B$ to the real line. The image is precisely $A/B$, and hence it is compact.

Comment: okay thanks for the help, i was thinking about a different method, that i could take 2 subsequences and show that their quotient converges to some a/b in A/B. this way A/B would be compact using the, converging subsequences-compactness theorem

Comment: Any working method, well, works. There are many ways to do this, I would say. :)